# Sitting shiva for a parent who married a gentile

Tags: halacha, intermarriage, sitting-shiva

Someone told me that if your parent marries a gentile, you are halachically not supposed to sit shiva for them when they pass away. This doesn't sound like it could be true.

Can you please clarify?

Comment: Not supposed to, or don't have to? It might depend on various factors. Also, for practical guidance, and I hope this is not, please CYLOR.

Answer (score 1):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus 12:2 quoting Yoreh Deah 345:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=) says that one who is a Mumar = convert to another religion, [Moseir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesirah), or Apikores = Heretic, there is no Aveilus for them unless they did Teshuva (repented), or are considered a [Tinok Shenishbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinok_shenishba).

If they were murdered or killed then Aveilus applies, as their death atones. [Rama Yore Deah 340:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=576).

Comment: I think the OP would benefit from less jargon in the answer. "Mumar", "Masur", "Apikores" "Aveilus" "Teshuva" "Tinok Shenishbo". And even with jargon, does the Nitei Gavriel specify which of those first three categories someone who intermarries would be part of?

Comment: Note "Masur" seems to be a (sloppy?) typo in the NG. The Shulchan Arukh says "Moseir" bc that's who is a doing something offensive.

Comment: Please clarify that your last sentence is from a different paragraph there with a different original source.

Comment: None of this answers the question at hand - someone who MARRIES A NON-JEW. That doesn't require converting, moseir, or heresy.