# Sitting shiva for intermarrying child

Tags: halacha, intermarriage, sitting-shiva

We all heard about families sitting shiva if a child marries out of faith.

1. Are there documented cases of this happening?  (With all the rites of Shiva, not just cutting the child out of the family.)
2. Is this halacha? Source?
3. If the child really dies at a later time, is there an obligation to sit shiva again?  Does this depend on whether he repented and returned between marriage and death?

Comment: Good questions, although I think 1 is a bit off topic as Jews not Judaism (2 and 3 are good questions, although I'm not sure whether they should be asked together or split into 2). And does Fiddler on the Roof count as a documented case? :)

Comment: The famous case for this is Rabbenu Gershom sitting Shiva when his son converted out of Judaism 1007 years ago

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you know of an early source of the story that Rabbenu Gershom sat "shiva" when his son allegedly converted?

Comment: Seems to me that #3 is a given Yes. The child is still Jewish, after all. As much as I like Fiddler on the Roof, Tevye doesn't always cite "The Good Book" correctly, and even Tevye knows that he's not a rabbi, even though it seems all his friends think he really knows everything, even if he is poor. So, no, it's not a good source.

Comment: partial dupe - answer to #3 - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60272/5275. I made the wrong assumption.

Comment: @Israel how early do you want? Isn't it in Rishonim? Tur or Mordechai or something like that. I don't know the earliest source.

Comment: @DoubleAA I found a good article about it in HaMa'yan המעין - גליון תמוז תשעג http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=29&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%FA%EE%E5%E6%20%FA%F9%F2%E2&id=764

Comment: @DanF - Even the Rabbi in Fiddler on The Roof doesn't always quote 'The Good Book' correctly

Comment: @chortkov2 The rabbi doesn't speak much. But, there's a good reason to excuse the rabbi. His "Good Book" is usually the Gemarrah, aka Torah "by heart".

Comment: @DanF I find that to be an underappreciated sad aspect of the reality in Europe as that play depicts.  Tevye talks about how "an eye for an eye and a tooth for a tooth leaves everyone blind and toothless."  Nowadays any 7 year old with a Little Midrash knows better.  He recognizes it, and sings in "If I were a Rich Man" about how he'd learn all day and "that would be the sweetest thing of all", but the extreme poverty didn't allow for basic education.  If I won the lottery, I'd learn all day too (without the chickens and turkeys and geese), but it's no comparison to Tevye's situation.

Comment: I heard  from Persian friends that in Iran, if someone intermarried, the entire city would sit shivah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Just pointing out that it's not clear if Rabbenu Gershom sat shiva (actually 14 days) on his son when he converted or when he actually died. The article that Israel cited brings differing opinions.